# MVC 5 - Issue using WebClient to render a webpage in PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, vb.net

I'm actually working on an intranet in MVC 5 using VB.

I have no other choice than displaying a WordPress frontpage in a PartalView on my Home/Index.

The issue is that my code displays first all the page in plain text, then right in html, in fact it looks like it return the page twice.

I tried many things such as a custom PartialViewResult but got other issues.

Here is my code in the **Controller** :

```
Function GetRemoteContent(url As Uri) As PartialViewResult

    Dim wsite As String = String.Empty

    Using webpage As WebClient = New WebClient()
        webpage.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent) = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
        webpage.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        wsite = webpage.DownloadString(url)
    End Using    

    Return PartialView("_PartialRemoteContent", wsite)

End Function
```

And my **Index View** :

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Home Page"
    Html.RenderAction("GetRemoteContent", New With {.url = New Uri("http://www.a-wordpress-front-page.com/")})
End Code
```

Finally my **PartalView** :

```
@Model
<div>
    @Html.Raw(Model)
</div>
```

Any idea on what is wrong here ? Thanks.

Comment: You should not embed a complete document within a document... use an iframe  :)

Comment: Well looks like there is no other solution. Thx @Laurent Lequenne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Laurent Lequin comments, iFrame is likely stills the best solution.

Dealing with sizing problems stills a challenge.